# How do I start a service from my Interactor using the MVP pattern in android?

Tags: java, android, service, mvp

I'm following the Model View Presenter (MVP) pattern similar to Antonio Leiva's example found here: [antoniolg/github](https://github.com/antoniolg/androidmvp).

I've been playing around with it quite a bit and I was wondering how I would start a `service` from the `interactor` layer. Normally I've been putting my `retrofit` calls inside the `interactor` but I was wondering if there is a way to start a service from the `interactor` so I could run my `retrofit` calls in the service instead. Problem here is that I don't have the activity context to run the service and it kind of defeats the purpose of the MVP if I were to expose the context to the `interactor`.

I'm also not quite sure if this is even a good thing to be doing (starting services from the interactor). I was thinking about starting services from the `presenter` layer instead, but I'm running towards dead ends on how I should be approaching this.

If there's a way around this, please help a fellow out? Or enlighten me if this is not a good approach.

Comment: Could you post some pseudo code for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Define class for example My App extends Application and define method like getAppInstance returns Application object and then add name attribute of this class to Applicqtion Tag in Manifest then call this method inside your use case to get context object and start your service

```java
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private MyApp instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        instance = this;

    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();

        instance = null;
    }

    public MyApp getInstance(){
        return  instance;

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide code examples or more details? The answer is a bit poor in content :-)

Comment: Define class for example My App extends Application and  define method like getAppContext returns Context abd then add name of this class yo Applicqtion Tag in Manifest th3n call this method inside your use case to get context object  and start your service