# Start a Service using MVP pattern

Tags: java, android, mvp

I've been reading about `MVP` and I'd like to ask a few questions :

In my project I use lots of `IntentService`s to make some network calls. I am guessing that those services belong to `Model` layer of my app. But since they have a reference to context I'm not sure how I have to do it. 
Should I just create another class `MyService` and in there start the `IntentService` ? Maybe add all those services in a `ServiceModule` using `Dagger 2` ?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34196781/how-do-i-start-a-service-from-my-interactor-using-the-mvp-pattern-in-android) but there's no answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep ApplicationContext in model classes, it's completely safe. You can read more about abilities of application context here https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/ 
The two main advantages of MVP are testability and layer separation. If you can easily create unit tests for your presenters and models, you're doing right